# Unexpected behavior: zip -r in bash

Tags: bash, zip

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date="20180313"
source_path="/Users/<user_name>/Source/Git/WSI"
installer_path="../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*"

echo "archive=$source_path/wsi_installers_$date.zip"
echo "path=$installer_path"

# Create the installer archive
zip -r "$source_path/wsi_installers_$date.zip" "$installer_path"
```

If the archive does not exist, it fails with:

```
zip warning: name not matched: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r /Users/<user_name>/Source/Git/WSI/wsi_installers_20180313.zip . -i ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*)
```

Though the echo statements indicate a correct path:

```
archive=/Users/<user_name>/Source/Git/WSI/wsi_installers_20180313.zip
path=../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*
```

I tried the recommended command (using the -i option) but it fails with:

```
zip warning: zip file empty
```

If I use the output from the echo statements and run the zip command manually:

```
zip -r /Users/<user_name>/Source/Git/WSI/wsi_installers_20180313.zip ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*
```

It works:

```
adding: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/ADP_Installers.hta (deflated 71%)
adding: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/StartHta.exe (deflated 71%)
adding: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/WSPCP_TDI/ (stored 0%)
...
adding: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/common/styles/plugins.css (deflated 85%)
adding: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/common/styles/table.css (deflated 80%)
adding: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/updatecenter/ (stored 0%)
```

Then when I run the script, it also works, with the output showing it is updating the archive:

```
updating: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/ADP_Installers.hta (deflated 71%)
updating: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/StartHta.exe (deflated 71%)
updating: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/WSPCP_TDI/ (stored 0%)
...
updating: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/common/styles/plugins.css (deflated 85%)
updating: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/common/styles/table.css (deflated 80%)
updating: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/updatecenter/ (stored 0%)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Add `set -x` to your script.  That'll show what it thinks is happening.

Comment: I bet the `*` in `installer_path` isn't getting expanded.

Comment: + zip -r /Users/barnesr/Source/Git/WSI/wsi_installers_20180313.zip '../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*'
 zip warning: name not matched: ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r /Users/barnesr/Source/Git/WSI/wsi_installers_20180313.zip . -i ../FE_Installer/cdk_installer/*)
+ exit

Comment: I suspected the '*' was a factor -- but why would it work when the ZIP exists?

Comment: Removing the '*' was the solution.  Thanks.  Add it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the `*` in `installer_path` isn't getting expanded.  Take the `*` out of `installer_path` and it'll work.

Comment: This doesn't explain why, it works, which is because the `*` was quoted, so `zip` was looking for literal file/dir named `*`. You can put asterisks immediately after quoted parameters to retain shell globbing.

Comment: @Walf that's mentioned in a comment I made to the question, before making an official answer.  I'll add it  to the answer for clarity.